# Why does it matter if I put my condition in the filter function or in mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am new to R and having difficulty understanding why I get a difference in values between the two pieces of code. Why does the code below return different results when I move `!is.na(arr_time)` from mutate to filter? My data is coming from the nycflights13 package.

```r
A <- flights %>%
      filter(!is.na(tailnum)) %>%
      mutate(on_time = !is.na(arr_time) & (arr_delay <= 0)) %>%
      group_by(tailnum) %>%
      summarise(on_time = mean(on_time), n = n()) %>%
      filter(min_rank(on_time) == 1)

B <- flights %>%
      filter(!is.na(tailnum), !is.na(arr_time)) %>%
      mutate(on_time = arr_delay <= 0) %>%
      group_by(tailnum) %>%
      summarise(on_time = mean(on_time), n = n()) %>%
      filter(min_rank(on_time) == 1)
```

Tibble A returns 110 observations while Tibble B returns 104 observations. When I separate the 6 unique observations between A and B and look them up in the flights data.frame, all 6 have observations where `arr_time == NA`. Shouldn't those be excluded in Tibble A based on the conditions in mutate? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Tibble A:

`mutate(on_time = !is.na(arr_time) & (arr_delay <= 0))` is saying "create a new column in my dataset called `on_time` which is true only when `arr_delay` is less than or equal to zero AND when `arr_time` is not NA." So whether `arr_time` is NA or not is a part of the resulting boolean (T/F) result that you're storing within this new column's value. In other words, no filtering is taking place due to if `arr_time` is NA. It's only being used to determine if the result should be TRUE or FALSE.

Regarding Tibble B:

`filter(!is.na(tailnum), !is.na(arr_time))` is saying "filter out observations (rows) where EITHER `tailnum` is NA, OR where `arr_time` is NA."

Let's consider a much simpler version of this same concept:

```
x <- c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4)

# "filter()" example
# filtering based on if values in x are NA:
x[!is.na(x)]

# equivalent to "mutate()" example where our result doesn't exclude NA
# values, they are simply used within our logic to determine T/F...
# determining the value of a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) based on if values in x are NA:
is.na(x)
```

Comment: "So whether arr_time is NA or not is a part of the resulting boolean (T/F) result that you're storing within this new column's value" This bit really helped connect all the dots.

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` filter function removes rows from a data frame. From the help of this function:

> Use filter() to choose rows/cases where conditions are true. Unlike
>   base subsetting with [, rows where the condition evaluates to NA are
>   dropped.

So rows that evaluate to NA are dropped. How many rows?

```
> sum(is.na(flights$arr_time))
[1] 8713
```

How many rows are you left with after filtering:

```
> sum(!is.na(flights$arr_time))
[1] 328063
```

If I run the first two lines of each of the two code blocks and check how many rows are left:

```
A <- flights %>%
  filter(!is.na(tailnum))
> nrow(A)
[1] 334264
```

and

```
B <- flights %>%
  filter(!is.na(tailnum), !is.na(arr_time))
> nrow(B)
[1] 328063
```

So by adding the `!is.na(arr_time)` clause in the filter function of B you are dropping the respective rows. Mutate does not drop rows; it changes or adds variables.
Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

`mutate` doesn't exclude. For your condition you will get `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In other words, `mutate` will generate a new column with values for each row of existing data. `filter` on the other hand can reduce the number of rows depending on your condition.